# createRecord on model with multiple relationships to same model gives a multiple possible inverse relationship error

Tags: ember.js

I have pinpointed some behavior I'd like to see if anyone can explain.

I made a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/iceking1624/PpWec/17/. To test behavior, open web console and simply type something in the textfield next to 'Add Question' button and then hit the button('Add Question').

Here are the `DS.Model` schemas:

```
App.Session = DS.Model.extend({
   "questions" : DS.hasMany('App.Question') ,
   "firstQuestion" : DS.belongsTo('App.Question')
});
App.Question = DS.Model.extend({
   "session" : DS.belongsTo('App.Session'),
   "choices" : DS.hasMany('App.Choice'),
   "text"    : DS.attr('string')
});
App.Choice = DS.Model.extend({
   "session"  : DS.belongsTo('App.Session'),
   "question" : DS.belongsTo('App.Question'),
   "text"     : DS.attr('string')
});
```

When I do the following inside `SessionController` then call the `addQuestion` function:

```
App.SessionController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   addQuestion: function() {
      var sessionModel = this.get('model');

      var question = App.Question.createRecord({
         "session" : sessionModel
      });

      this.get('questions').pushObject(question)
   }
});
```

I get the following 'error' but it functions as expected nonetheless:

> Error: assertion failed: You defined the 'session' relationship on
>   App.Question, but multiple possible inverse relationships of type
>   App.Question were found on App.Session.

Now I figured out it's because inside `App.Session` I have two fields that reference `App.Question`:

```
   "questions" : DS.hasMany('App.Question') ,
   "firstQuestion" : DS.belongsTo('App.Question')
```

but I'm wondering why Ember cares that I have multiple `App.Question` relationships?? And especially why it would throw an error, yet work perfectly. Is this a bug perhaps?

Is there a way I can make Ember happy and not throw an error??? I really need that `firstQuestion` field in my App.Session model.

Open the console and look at my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iceking1624/PpWec/17/). It's a perfect example of my issue. Then try commenting out `firstQuestion` in the `App.Session = DS.Model` and watch how the error magically disappears

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I found a solution. I hope this helps somebody in the future!

Apparently it was improper to define multiple relationships to the same model as I did, without being a bit more descriptive...

Below I have both `questions` and `firstQuestion` pointing to `App.Question` and Ember did not like that I was so vague!

```
App.Session = DS.Model.extend({
   "questions" : DS.hasMany('App.Question') ,
   "firstQuestion" : DS.belongsTo('App.Question')
});
```

To reduce chances for miscommunication (and rid an annoying error), the inverse relation can be explicitly defined as below:

```
App.Session = DS.Model.extend({
    "questions" : DS.hasMany('App.Question', { inverse: 'session' }),
    "firstQuestion" : DS.belongsTo('App.Question')
});
App.Question = DS.Model.extend({
    "session" : DS.belongsTo('App.Session', { inverse: 'questions' }),
    "choices" : DS.hasMany('App.Choice'),
    "text"    : DS.attr('string')
});
```

this got rid of the error. If anyone else has more insight or even criticism I'd be interested to hear.

Comment: Still helping 20 november 2013 hehe.